# Floating background image

Tags: css, css-float

On my [site](http://www.olmasigereken.com/demo/) there is an input form and a track picture. If you resize your browser window track will crash into the form. Eventhough track is not an independent image, is it possible floating a background image?
css:

```
#header{
    height:212px;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    border-bottom:2px solid #66675e;
    background:url(img/truck.gif) no-repeat 150px 55px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to prevent collisions between your truck background-image and your elements contained in the same div having the background image, I would sugest to have a minimum width for your div.

Another solution would be to make your divs floatable AND add a minimum width (extract the style into a css, replace a and b with your size and perform the computations):

```
<div id="header" style="min-width: (a+b)px;">
    <div style="float: left; width: (a)px;"><img src="truck"/></div>
    <div style="width: (b)px; margin: auto;"><form..../></div>
</div>
```

This should give you a start

Comment: This won't do anything without Javascript... and moreover, you shouldn't use inline styles if you can avoid it.

Comment: This didn't give me a start. I am sorry, maybe i am a css yahoo.

Comment: **cereallarceny** >> it is solely an example.

Comment: **Laura Smit** >> It worked for me. Still interested on this solution? Want a fully featured example?